# Understanding the cell size argument in the kriging tool, ArcGIS

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, kriging

I'm not quite understanding the cell size values that a given raster has. I've been doing some kriging interpolation on very dense point data and if I leave the cell size parameter blank, it's cell size is like an extremely small number, like e-006.

What does this extremely small cell size number mean? I always known that the cell size of a raster is the size of the cell that each value of the raster represents spatially. But with such a tiny number, doesn't seem to make sense.  When running the Kriging tool and if I enter a whole number, like 1 for the cell size, it just errors out. If I zoom into the raster and measure the size of the cell pixels, they look like there around 3 ft by 3 ft in size. Am I confusing cell size with pixel size here? If so, what determines the size of the pixels?

Comment: Thanks Michael, that totally answers it.  If you move this to an answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you leave the cell size blank you are telling ArcMap to choose its own, by your admission you've indicated that the data is dense so a small cell size would be suitable. e-006 means 6th decimal place (so 1e-006 is 0.000001). Is your source data in geographic coordinates (lat/lon)? this would explain the difference in cell dimensions i.e. stored in geographic, measured in projected and why it freaks out on whole numbers (1 degree is a BIG number). Try projecting to a suitable projected coordinate system before using kriging.